# C# Modeless Dialog: How to return 3 different values from modeless dialog to main form and put them together to use as Color.FromARGB?

Tags: c#

I have this code that I am working on and I need to return 3 values from a single modeless dialog so I can use it as Color.FromARGB. How is possible to do that?

Comment: return them as properties of a single object..?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: The thing is in my modeless dialog, I have three track bar, one of each for red, green, blue. In the main form, I have a label and the backColor of the label needs to change to the corresponding color as the trackbars scroll up and down. Like, i know how to return the value from single trackbar, to the main form but now I am confused how to do with three.

Comment: Alright as you know how to return single value from trackbar to main form. You have two option to achieve result - 1, in your dialog take a "Color" object and apply all three trackers RGB value to it and return single "Color" object to main form.    2, Take a custom class and add three int properties to it for R,G,B. Set relative tracker value to property and then return that object to main view. I hope you are getting this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you want to do is to have this color dialog expose all the properties you want to make available to other dialogs/processes. In your case, you could just expose the values for red, green and blue as integer representations of three trackbars or textboxes or numeric updowns... it doesn't really matter the control you use, as long as you can expose their values through public properties.

Then, wire the changes of the trackbars (or textboxes) to an event which can be captured by the calling form and then have the calling form query the three properties and build a color using the `Color.FromArgb` method.

[Here's a very simple example](https://xfx.net/stackoverflow/SO_ColorDialog/SO_ColorDialog.7z).

Note that there are many ways in which you can share data between forms. This is just one of them.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way of using delegates?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In the sample I use a delegate to provide an event handler.